# Why is this Google scripts code not modifying values in cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to have the script check the area of study column and increase the cells in Reputation/Gold/Experience based on their area of study?

[image]

```
    function checkPassive(){
  var study = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Kingdom DB Backend").getRange("KingdomDB");
  var i=0;
  for(i;i<100;i++){
    if(study.getCell(7+i, 5) == "Nobility" ){
      Nobility_Passive(i, study);
    }else if(study.getCell(7+i, 5) == "Economy"){
      Economy_Passive(i, study); 
    }else if(study.getCell(7+i, 5) == "Military"){
      Military_Passive(i, study);
    }
  }
}

function Nobility_Passive(i, study) {
 study.getCell(7+i, 9).setValue(study.getCell(7+i, 9).getValue() + 50);
}

function Economy_Passive(i, study) {
 study.getCell(7+i, 10).setValue(study.getCell(7+i, 10).getValue() + 5);
}

function Military_Passive(i, study) {
 study.getCell(7+i, 4).setValue(study.getCell(7+i, 4).getValue() + 500);
}
```

Below is the CSV of the Spreadsheet on previous attempts to change the code the script would run but it would only add the 500 to Military rows and add no gold or reputation to the Economy or Nobility rows.

```
 Kingdom ID Username    Level   Area of Study   Experience  PvP bonus   Rank    Class   Reputation  Gold    Quests completed    Buildings owned Unit Count
1   Jeoyun  100             King    Lore: Bard  10000   10000   10000   10000   10000
2   girthy_winner   99              Grand Vizier    Druid   9999    9999    9999    9999    9999
4   Zoiphri 8   Nobility    36500       Peasant Rogue   750 85  7   0   0
7   mochi_hime  6   Economy 24500   1   Peasant Monk    455 82  6   0   0
10  voodeer 5   Nobility    20500       Peasant Cleric  250 5   5   0   0
6   ZOOMIN_IN_THE_4HEAD 5   Nobility    19000   1   Peasant Paladin 250 25  4   0   0
18  DoctorTrain 4       12000       Peasant Sorcerer    -50 0   2   0   0
3   Daemoj  4       9000        Peasant Rogue   275 15  2   0   0
12  Skarnmo 3       7500        Peasant Bard    -150    0   2   0   0
19  catsatonamat    3   Military    6500        Peasant Sorcerer    0   20  3   0   0
13  evilkiba29  1       2000        Peasant     0   0   1   0   0
5   shadowfoxgamerr 0   Military    500     Peasant Rogue   0   0   1   0   0
8   shyestrife  0       500     Peasant     0   0   0   0   0
9   SireenH_    0       0       Peasant     0   0   0   0   0
11  eWqUiOeQw12378  0       0       Peasant Barbarian   0   0   0   0   0
14  fakiekingz  0       0       Peasant     0   0   0   0   0
15  LoreCraft   0       0       Peasant     0   0   0   0   0
16  King_Harkinian  0       0       Peasant     0   0   0   0   0
17  mokhster    0       0       Peasant     0   0   0   0   0
20  NaokiiSama  0       0       Peasant Sorcerer    0   5   1   0   0
21  42getafix   1   Nobility    4000    1   Peasant Warlock 1550    58  1   0   0
22  hadou1000   0       0       Peasant Paladin 50  5   1   0   0
23  dragonicafro    0       0       Peasant     0   0   0   0   0
24  RaizerSkybreaker    0       0       Peasant     0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Could you describe a little more details what you expect to happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: I am trying to have this script check the Area of study column seen on the attached picture, if the area of study is "Economy" i want it to add 5 to the Gold cell in the same row, if the area of study is "Military" i want it to add 500 to the Experience cell of the same Row, if the area of study is "Nobility" i want it to add 50 to the Reputation cell of the same row. It will run the script with no errors but will change no values.

Comment: getCell() returns a range not a value. Read about [getValue() or getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: Try `if(study.getCell(7+i, 5).getValue() == "Nobility" )`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function checkPassive(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Kingdom DB Backend');
  var study=ss.getRangeByName("KingdomDB");

  for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
    if(study.getCell(7+i,5).getValue().trim()=="Nobility" ){
      Nobility_Passive(i,study);
    }else if(study.getCell(7+i,5).getValue().trim()=="Economy"){
      Economy_Passive(i,study); 
    }else if(study.getCell(7+i,5).getValue().trim()=="Military"){
      Military_Passive(i,study);
    }
  }
}

function Nobility_Passive(i,study) {
 study.getCell(7+i, 9).setValue(study.getCell(7+i, 9).getValue() + 50);
}

function Economy_Passive(i, study) {
 study.getCell(7+i, 10).setValue(study.getCell(7+i, 10).getValue() + 5);
}

function Military_Passive(i, study) {
 study.getCell(7+i, 4).setValue(study.getCell(7+i, 4).getValue() + 500);
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it only changes the millitary Xp cells

Comment: Try it again.  I added trim() because often an extra space is added to a string.

Comment: I'll  debug your code for you if you can provide the spreadsheet data as csv.  You can just past it into a code section and I can copy it right out of that.

Comment: That would be much appreciated I have posted the spreadsheet data in the code section

Comment: You need to post it as csv.

Comment: when i try to download it from sheets it just downloads as CSV (Comma Delimited) how to i save it as a CSV?

Comment: Just open the file up and copy it and then paste it into the edit window select all and press control K

Comment: I guess I should have said open the file up in an ascii text editor and then copy it as a string and paste into the edit window and the select it all and press control K.  Don't open it up with a spreadsheet.  Do you see any commas in the data?  I don't either.